# need some help to my sql query

Tags: mysql, database

I have buttons of categories and what I'm trying to do is when i click on a button (that present one category) I want to display all the questions of this category.

I have two tables:

**Questions** and I have the following fields:

```
questionsID,questions,categories_categoriesID, languages_languagesID
```

**Categories** and I have the following fields:

```
categoriesID , categorytype
```

I have a problem with the query.
what I have done so far but does not work is here:

```
SELECT questions FROM Questions WHERE categories_categoriesID == categoriesID FROM Categories;
```

Comment: You need to do a join between those two tables. Search for mySQL SELECT JOIN to see the syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Questions
JOIN Categories
ON categoriesID = categgories_categoriesID
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL Query is wrong. You are trying to join the two tables which isn't needed as you can get the questions based on a category through the **categories_categoriesID**. Try to read some more on SQL Queries.
Here are some resources:

1. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/
2. https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/

The right SQL Query would be:

```
SELECT questions FROM Questions 
  WHERE categories_categoriesID = <The Category ID Based On The Button>
```

You have to give the button a specific **categoriesID** that would replace the value inside the query. For example, if Button 1 would refer to category 19 then the query should be:

```
SELECT questions FROM Questions 
  WHERE categories_categoriesID = 19
```